# Manipulating ASP.NET Databound Query

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

I've got a Databound DropDownList control that is filled with the following query:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelector" runat="server" DataSourceID="dataSelector"
  DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
  AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSelector" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM [Status]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have a second Databound DropDownList control who's values need to be selected from the next available `Status.ID`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeTo" runat="server" DataSourceID="dataChangeTo"
  DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataChangeTo" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM [Status] WHERE ([Description] &lt; @Description)">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelector" Name="Description" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The `WHERE` clause above does not fit the solution I am after. It is filtering alphabetically.

What I need is a way to get the `[ID]` value from `ddlSelector` and put all values greater than that `ID` into my `ddlChangeTo` control.

How do I get the `[ID]` value from the `ddlSelector` DropDownList control to use in the Databinding query for the `ddlChangeTo` DropDownList control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out how to do this, but I did not find the answer online anywhere.

After starring at the code for a bit and trying various ways, it appears that `DataTextField` is what is displayed while `DataValueField` is the value that is used for comparison.

This may be obvious to those of you who have done this for a long time, but it was not for me.

To get my control to work, I made the following change to the `DataValueField` of the `ddlSelector` DropDownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelector" runat="server" DataSourceID="dataSelector"
  DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
  AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I had to make a similar change to the second Databound DropDownList control, the `SqlDataSource`, and the `ControlParameter` Type:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeTo" runat="server" DataSourceID="dataChangeTo"
  DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataChangeTo" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM [Status] WHERE ([ID] &gt; @ID)">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelector" Name="Description" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Such a cool feeling when you figure it out yourself.

I hope others get some use out of this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to wrap the entire section in a update panel and bind the second dropdown after the first one has changed.

You could then hook up the asp:ControlParameter to a hidden field and have the first dropdown list populate the hidden field in the code behind on autopostback before calling the databind on the second dropdown.

Comment: Swing! Right over my head, Rob. I've already got an Update Panel on the form to keep the data refreshed every 30 seconds. If I had to resort to code behind, wouldn't it be easier to just populate the entire DropDownList in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? I was under the impression that Databinding was better, so I was trying to make that work.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out (see answer that I can't accept for 2 more days).